# How to delete all nodes that do not have any relationships - neo4j/cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am generating nodes in a neo4j database and want to remove those that have no relationships. What is the best cypher instruction to do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE size((n)--())=0
DELETE (n)
```

Comment: The query is correct, but could be slow with large graphs and lots of relationships, since it has to walk through all relationships to calculate size. The following should be more efficient: `match (n)
where not (n)--()
delete (n)`

Comment: Doesn't size use node.getDegree()?

Comment: There is no evidence in the documentation about it.

Comment: It is the most efficient way, profile shows it is using getDegree

Comment: @remigio my bad for writes it still not use getDegree, need to be tested in 2.3

Comment: @remigio yes, for updating queries it uses the rule planner. Re-profiled, and time to execute is still less with size over not(pattern) but should be tested against a large graph