# Efficiently check if there is at least one relationship of type connected to node, if not - remove node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let's assume this `Neo4j` data construct.

`(:Store)<-[:FROM]-(:Notification)-[:FOR]->(//users//:User)`

Which should serve as, for example, a notification for users on a new sale in a store.
Such a notification may be addressed to a large number of users simultaneously, in this case I can see two approaches for this data modelling:

1. Create separate `:Notification` with relationships for each of the `:User`'s; All connected to single `:Store` node. So when notification is received - relationships and `:Notification` node is removed.
2. Approach which i thought should be more effective performance wise and about which my question is: Create a single `:Notification` node connected to a store and multiple `[:FOR]`'s for different users. Notification received - `:FOR` for this user removed, if no `:FOR`'s left - `:Notification` itself removed .

So my questions are:
Am I correct in assuming that the 2nd one is a better practice?
How can I generally, after deleting a relationship, check if there are more such relationships, and do it without making Neo4j match all connected ones of this type, i.e check if there is at least one relationship of this type left?

Comment: @davejagoda thanks for edits! =)

Comment: Rather than remove the relationship and lose sight of the fact that it was sent in the first place why not just update the relationship as `{received: true}`.

Comment: @DaveBennett why will i need to keep sight on it after user somehow dispatched it? (ok/accept/decline e.t.c) If i will keep them then, given some time, i will have a decent amount of garbage in DB

Comment: fair enough - i was just curious if it was a possible consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely having fewer objects created in the first place would be more efficient in general. It will result in *2n* fewer objects (1 node and relationship per user). The exception would be if you had so many users per notification that the node density was too high.  To avoid that though you could simply create additional notifications at a particular user threshold.

The following query is adapted from @Luanne's answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33559454/how-to-delete-all-nodes-that-do-not-have-any-relationships-neo4j-cypher) which i though was pretty slick.

It presumes that besides the `User` nodes, the only other connection to the `Notification` nodes is the store nodes. If the degree of nodes connected to the `Notification` node is one then it must be just a `Store` node remaining. Remove the relationship to the `Store` node and remove then remove the `Notification` node.

```
MATCH (n:Notification {name: 'Notification One'} )-[store_rel:FROM]->(s:Store)
WHERE size((n)--())=1
DELETE store_rel, n
```

Comment: It looks logical to me that to obtain size neo will need to match all of the pattern's occurences, or am i mistaken and neo will in fact just check if there is at least one and then stop?
What do you mean "node density was too high"? Where this "too high" starts and what it can cause?

Comment: Yes, I think that it does result in a lot of DB hits.  I mocked up some data and added `PROFILE` to the query the way I had it originally and it does indeed result in counting each relationship. I updated it to assume that the relationship from the notification to the store would be the last relationship standing.  The profiler says this is a much better query.  As far as too high - from what I have read - when nodes start to get ~100k relationships they are considered very dense.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! i'll fiddle around with it as soon as get back to neo4j part of an app.

Comment: I'm back! So i have fiddled around with it. Thng is im trying to achieve deleting of relationship and removing note if non relationships left in one query, so im using delete user relationship->with notification->match notification->where (no more left)->optional match(to get all other relationship that should be cleaned up)->delete all

Comment: Also a small problem is that amount of non-user relationships left may warry. So I have tryed out WHERE size((n)-[:FOR]-())=0 and WHERE NOT (n)-[:FOR]-(). Profiler reporting same amount of hits and both using the same planner (RULE). so i gone for WHERE NOT as it is just looks a bit more logically pleasing for me.